# Positioning a div between two others

Tags: css, css-float, sass

I have 3 divs vertically. The first should have 100% width, the second should have an image with width 283px, and third div should have 100% width.
Does anyone know how to position the image div in the middle of two others divs 100%?

I've tried this, but dont works for me

```
<div class="content">
<div class="first">1</div>
<div class="third">3</div>
<div class="second">2</div>
</div>

.first{
  width:100%;
  float:left;
  background:yellow;
}
.third{
   width:100%
   float:right;
   background:pink;
}
.second{
   width:283px;
   overflow:hidden;
   background:blue;
}​enter code here
```

Comment: Why not make it 100% too, and then then use `text-align: center` to centralize the image?

Comment: So do you want them side by side, or one on top of the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your intention is to position the divs next to each other horizontally than you can't have any of them set to a width of 100% as the total of all elements next to each other can only total 100%.

If your website will be fixed width than your easiest solution would be to set the width of the left and right div in pixels to the (width of the site - 283) / 2. Then they would float next to each other. You could also do this with %.

However if your site is fluid width, then you would need to work out a percentage for all 3 divs i.e 33% each but this would mean the middle won't be exactly 283px.

The only way I can think to make this work exactly as you want would be to use Javascript to resize the elements after the page load which could then get the browser dimensions and work it all out.

Answer (score 0):

Having read it a few times i think i get what you want to do.

You want he middle div to be centred between the two other divs.

you need to give the div a class something like this:

```
 .middlediv
 {
    width: 283px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 }
```

which can also be written like this:

```
 .middlediv
 {
    width: 283px;
    margin: 0px auto;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear, so I've done both possible interpretations: http://jsfiddle.net/EbBzY/

HTML

```
<h1>Option 1</h1>
<div class="main">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="first">1</div>
        <div class="second">2</div>
        <div class="third">3</div>
    </div>
</div>

<h1>Option 2</h1>
<div class="content">
    <div class="first">1</div>
    <div class="second">2</div>
    <div class="third">3</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.main{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom:100px;
}
.main .content{
    display:table-row;
}
.main .content div{
    display:table-cell;
}

.first{
    background:yellow;
}
.third{
    background:pink;
}
.second{
    background:blue;
    width:283px;
    margin:auto;
}
```